# parsing html table using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I wrote this code for printing a table as seen in here http://www.medindia.net/drug-price/list.asp

```
import mechanize
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

med="paracetamol"
br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
res=br.open("http://www.medindia.net/drug-price/")
br.select_form("frmdruginfo_search")
br.form['druginfosearch']=med
br.submit()
url=br.response().geturl()
print url
web_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page)
tabl=soup.find_all('table')
rows=tabl.find_all('tr')

for tr in rows:
        cols=tr.find_all('td')
        for td in cols:
              text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
              print text+"|",
```

But while I execute the same I get this error

```
 rows=tabl.find_all('tr')
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`soup.find_all('table')` returns a list of matched tables, you just need the one - use `find()`:

```
tabl = soup.find('table', {'class': 'content-table'})
rows = tabl.find_all('tr')
```

Also note that I'm explicitly saying that I need a table with a specific class.

Also you don't need to make a separate `urllib2` call to the page - just use `br.response().read()` for getting an actual html for BS to parse.

Just FYI, if you want a better formatted table results on a console, consider using [texttable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable):

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import texttable


med = raw_input("Enter the drugname: ")
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
res = br.open("http://www.medindia.net/drug-price/")
br.select_form("frmdruginfo_search")
br.form['druginfosearch'] = med
br.submit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())

tabl = soup.find('table', {'class': 'content-table'})
table = texttable.Texttable()
for tr in tabl.find_all('tr'):
    table.add_row([td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')])

print table.draw()
```

prints:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| SNo          | Prescribing  | Total No of  | Single       | Combination  |
|              | Information  | Brands       |     Generic  |     of       |
|              |              | (Single+Comb |              | Generic(s)   |
|              |              | ination)     |              |              |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1            | Abacavir     | 6            | View Price   | -            |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2            | Abciximab    | 1            | View Price   | -            |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 3            | Acamprosate  | 3            | View Price   | -            |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 4            | Acarbose     | 41           | View Price   | -            |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
...
```

Comment: For some reason, testing *exactly* this on my end results into an `ArraySizeError` for `texttable`. For some reason, the headers also include `1` and `Abacavir` on my first row. Hmm. Curious.

Comment: @BK201 Hm, what drug your are searching for testing? (just so I can reproduce your problem on my end)

Comment: Exactly OP's code above (paracetamol), but with your variation. It throws: `texttable.ArraySizeError: array should contain 5 elements`. Weird.

Comment: @BK201 here's the [code](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/9254060) I'm using. Please check. Entering paracetamol and it works fine..

Comment: And here's [mine](https://dyp.im/QwpVO3dlhY). Screenshot as I want to show the error. Code is not different at all. Checking your code...

Comment: @BK201, thanks. Could you debug it a bit then: print out `tr` inside the loop to see on what row it is failing?

Comment: Yep, just threw the same error with your exact code. Tried changing my `class_=...` to the same one as yours (`{'class':...}`) and still nothing. Will print out `tr` as requested. :)

Comment: A very deserved +1: TextTable looks nice, and learned a different approach from this answer. :)